# Can you provide an example use for `zrun`?

Tags: command-line

I was reading the manual pages for the package moreutils but I did not understand the page for `zrun`.

My manual page is almost the same as the [die.net one](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zrun):

```
ZRUN(1)                                                                ZRUN(1)



NAME
       zrun - automatically uncompress arguments to command

SYNOPSIS
       zrun command file.gz [...]

DESCRIPTION
       Prefixing a shell command with "zrun" causes any compressed files that
       are arguments of the command to be transparently uncompressed to temp
       files (not pipes) and the uncompressed files fed to the command.

       This is a quick way to run a command that does not itself support
       compressed files, without manually uncompressing the files.

       The following compression types are supported: gz bz2 Z xz lzma lzo

       If zrun is linked to some name beginning with z, like zprog, and the
       link is executed, this is equivalent to executing "zrun prog".

BUGS
       Modifications to the uncompressed temporary file are not fed back into
       the input file, so using this as a quick way to make an editor support
       compressed files won't work.

AUTHOR
       Copyright 2006 by Chung-chieh Shan <ccshan@post.harvard.edu>



moreutils                         2010-04-28                           ZRUN(1)
```

Can you provide an example use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example;

```
$ cat >afile
This is a file
line2
line3
$ cp afile bfile
$ gzip afile
$ ls -l
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 usera usera 48 2014-02-19 13:24 afile.gz
-rw-r--r-- 1 usera usera 27 2014-02-19 13:24 bfile
```

*with grep*

```
$ grep line *
bfile:line2
bfile:line3
```

*with zrun*

```
$ zrun grep line *
/tmp/dpQH01hY51-afile:line2
/tmp/dpQH01hY51-afile:line3
bfile:line2
bfile:line3
```

You can see that `grep` doesn't see proper lines in the zipped up `afile.gz`. However when using `zrun`,

`zrun` first unzips `afile.gz` into `/tmp` and the actual command executed by `zrun` is:

```
$ grep line /tmp/dpQH01hY51-afile bfile
```